# Tensor Filling with last digit of inner Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to fill a 2d tensor with the last inner tensor having the last value become the full row of the new tensor. This probably doesn't make sense, so here is an example given tensora = [[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[4,3,4],[2,3,7]]. The new tensor would be [[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[4,4,4],[7,7,7]]. Which is the last value of the inner tensor.

what I have tried is

```
tf.fill(input_layer.shape, input_layer[:,-1])
```

This Raises value errors:

> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.fill" (type TFOpLambda).
> Tried to convert 'dims' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape (None, 32, 1024) to a Tensor.
> Call arguments received by layer "tf.fill" (type TFOpLambda):
> • dims=TensorShape([None, 32, 1024])
> • value=tf.Tensor(shape=(1024,), dtype=float32)
> • name=None

Any help on how to fix this error or an alternative way to do this would be nice. The purpose of doing this is for one of the inputs of the informer pre-trained model by hugging the face. I need the past observed features, which I have stored in the last dimensional output. If there is a simpler way to do this where the past observed feature is somewhere different, I can change the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tf.fill()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) api accepts the paramenter dims (the tensor shape) and value (scaler tensor), but you are giving value - as array which is causing this error.

So the one way of doing this using loop as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_layer = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[4,3,4],[2,3,7]])
print(input_layer)
print("Dims:",input_layer.shape)
print("Value:",input_layer[:,-1])
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 3]
 [2 2 2]
 [4 3 4]
 [2 3 7]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32)
Dims: (4, 3)
Value: tf.Tensor([3 2 4 7], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

using `For` loop:

```
#tf.fill(input_layer.shape, input_layer[:,-1])
y=[]
for i in input_layer:
    x = tf.fill(i.shape, i[-1]).numpy() #as tensors are immutable
    y.append(x) 
z = tf.convert_to_tensor(y)
z
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [7, 7, 7]], dtype=int32)>
```